# How to correctly set input image size for LPRNet model? 'RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1..'

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

Trying to adapt the LPRNet model for my own dataset. The original model was set for Chinese license plate images with dimensions 24x94 pixels. My dataset consists of plates with only numbers, images come with dimensions 64x128. I got an error when I try to replace 'summary(lprnet, (3,24,94), device="cpu")' to 'summary(lprnet, (3,64,128), device="cpu")'.
The first code is working well, the second gets 'RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Got 25 and 24 in dimension 3 (The offending index is 1)', this is the last line of code.
I don't see where else in the code I should change parameters. Will be thankful for any clue!
Original: https://github.com/xuexingyu24/License_Plate_Detection_Pytorch/blob/master/LPRNet/model/LPRNET.py

```
# LPRNET model
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchsummary import summary

class small_basic_block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ch_in, ch_out):
        super(small_basic_block, self).__init__()
        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(ch_in, ch_out // 4, kernel_size=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(ch_out // 4, ch_out // 4, kernel_size=(3, 1), padding=(1, 0)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(ch_out // 4, ch_out // 4, kernel_size=(1, 3), padding=(0, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(ch_out // 4, ch_out, kernel_size=1),
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)

class LPRNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, class_num, dropout_rate):
        super(LPRNet, self).__init__()
        self.class_num = class_num
        self.backbone = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1), # 0
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),  # 2
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1)),
            small_basic_block(ch_in=64, ch_out=128),    # *** 4 ***
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=128),
            nn.ReLU(),  # 6
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), stride=(2, 1, 2)),
            small_basic_block(ch_in=64, ch_out=256),   # 8
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(),  # 10
            small_basic_block(ch_in=256, ch_out=256),   # *** 11 ***
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),   # 12
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), stride=(4, 1, 2)),  # 14
            nn.Dropout(dropout_rate),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(1, 4), stride=1),  # 16
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(),  # 18
            nn.Dropout(dropout_rate),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=class_num, kernel_size=(13, 1), stride=1), # 20
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=class_num),
            nn.ReLU(),  # *** 22 ***
        )
        self.container = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256+class_num+128+64, out_channels=self.class_num, kernel_size=(1,1), stride=(1,1)),
            # nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=self.class_num),
            # nn.ReLU(),
            # nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.class_num, out_channels=self.lpr_max_len+1, kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            # nn.ReLU(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        keep_features = list()
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.backbone.children()):
            x = layer(x)
            if i in [2, 6, 13, 22]: # [2, 4, 8, 11, 22]
                keep_features.append(x)

        global_context = list()
        for i, f in enumerate(keep_features):
            if i in [0, 1]:
                f = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=5, stride=5)(f)
            if i in [2]:
                f = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(4, 10), stride=(4, 2))(f)
            f_pow = torch.pow(f, 2)
            f_mean = torch.mean(f_pow)
            f = torch.div(f, f_mean)
            global_context.append(f)

        x = torch.cat(global_context, 1)
        x = self.container(x)
        logits = torch.mean(x, dim=2)

        return logits
    
CHARS = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
     
    lprnet = LPRNet(class_num=len(CHARS), dropout_rate=0)
    print(lprnet)
    
    summary(lprnet, (3,24,94), device="cpu")
    #summary(lprnet, (3,64,128), device="cpu")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the shapes of four tensors in global_context are different for (64, 128) input size. For shape (24, 94), in `LRPNet`, the authors make all the tensors of (4, 18) sized with average pooling which doesn't apply to your image size. To make them same-sized, you need to change the configurations of `nn.AvgPool2d` while enumerating `keep_features`. You may update them in various ways. I updated the avgpool with the below configurations and it worked:

````
            if i in [0, 1]:
                f = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(11, 24), stride=(7, 4))(f)

            elif i == 2:
                f = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(9, 11), stride=(7, 2))(f)
            elif i == 3:
                f = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(7, 2), stride=(5, 1))(f)
            f_pow = torch.pow(f, 2)
            f_mean = torch.mean(f_pow)
            f = torch.div(f, f_mean)
            global_context.append(f)```
````

Comment: Thank you very much, Labiba! This works for me too, can you please explain in some more detail how did you find the solution? I try to understand how the input size of (24,94) is related to tensors sized (4,18). And how did you find out these tensors size of (4,18)?

Comment: Firstly, I got the shapes of the global_context tensors. In the original code, they take all global_context tensors to shape (4, 18) by doing average pooling. However, in your case, the shapes were bigger. To make them all (4, 18) would need a lot of information squeezing. So I changed all the shapes to (8, 26) by doing averagepooling.
While doing average pooling, to find the kernel size and stride of each operation, I just followed the math for H_{out} and W_{out} from this page: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AvgPool2d.html#avgpool2d

Hope it helps.

Comment: It really helps, thank you very much for the explanation. I have used these formulas for solving another problem as well!